# Nhibernate: how to add AddAll method for 'Sets'?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, set, mapping

Since I installed current version of Nhibernate (version 4.0.0.4000) Iesi.Collections.Generic.HashedSet is not longer included.

I used this collection type in many parts of my code, because it has a "AddAll" method, which it very useful for me.

However - now in the same namespace are only 3 types left:
    `LinkedHashSet<T>`
    `ReadOnlySet<T>`
    `SychronizedSet<T>`

None of them has such a method. 
I tried to implement it by myself, but it does not work.

Here is what I did:

1. Created an interface "IMySet"

   public interface IMySet : ISet
   {
       void AddAll(IEnumerable items);
   }
2. Copied full source from "LinkedHashSet" implementation, renamed it to "TestSet" and replaced the derived interface.

before:

```
public class TestSet<T> : ISet<T>
```

after:

```
public class TestSet<T> : IMySet<T>
```

Unfortunately this does not work. If I try to save an object, which implements IMySet, an error occurs:

NHibernate.Tuple.Entity.PocoEntityTuplizer.SetPropertyValuesWithOptimizer(Object entity, Object[] values)

I don't understand what's the problem. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is, that NHibernate can/will use implementation of `ISet<T>` - which is available in NHibernate distribution *(dll)*. Most likely the `PersistentGenericSet<T>`.

Brand new interface `IMySet<T>` is simply not expected... not supported.

But this could be "easily" solved by some custom extension:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static bool AddAll<T>(this ISet<T> list, IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        // some very simple implementation:
        bool success = true;
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            success &= list.Add(item);
        }
        return success;
    }
}
```

And then we can use it as we used to:

```
// entity with ISet
public class MyEntity
{
    ...
    public virtual ISet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

// some method adding more items
var myEntity = ...
myEntity.Employees.AddAll(collectionOfEmployees)
```

Comment: This is just awesome! Thank you very much. But.. I don't get it. Why does it work? I've never seen before to use a static class that way. Can you tell me where I can find some more information about this technique?

Comment: This is called ["Extension methods"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx). It does improve reading, while in fact - it is just a syntactic sugar for us devs... Enjoy them and NHibernate as well ;)

Comment: Thank you again. That 'sugar' is great - I am really wondering why I never heard that before. For all other readers: here is a simple tutorial:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/new-orcas-language-feature-extension-methods
 You helped me a lot. Thumbs up ;)

Comment: Explanation of set types is correct, but the implementation is not required. This is already available as ISet<T>.UnionWith().

Answer (score 6):

The correct solution is to use the equivalent [`UnionWith()` method from .Net's `ISet<T>'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd411713%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Modifies the current set so that it contains all elements that are present in either the current set or the specified collection.

Example:

```
ISet<int> set = new Hashset<int>();
set.UnionWith(newElements);
```